# How do I parse 天津图书馆园区馆 (tiān jīn tú shū guǎn yuán qū guǎn)?

Tags: translation, meaning

I saw the road sign photographed below, but I'm confused about how 天津图书馆园区馆 (tiān jīn tú shū guǎn yuán qū guǎn) makes sense.

I'm mostly familiar with the components:

- [天津](http://dict.cn/%E5%A4%A9%E6%B4%A5) = Tianjin, the city I live in.
- [图书馆](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%BE%E4%B9%A6%E9%A6%86) = library
- [园](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%AD) usually refers to a park
- [区](http://dict.cn/%E5%8C%BA) = district (what we would call a suburb in Australia)
- [馆](http://dict.cn/%E9%A6%86) = ???

I don't recall seeing 馆 by itself before (always part of something else: 宾馆 （hotel), 博物馆 (museum), 体育馆 (gym), etc.), so I'm surprised as to what it's doing here.  This contributes to my confusion.

I'm also unsure of how to piece these together.

**Question**: How do I parse 天津图书馆园区馆?

[image: 天津图书馆园区馆 (along with the pinyin) on a road sign]

Comment: If 天津图书馆 refers to a public library, it may have several branch public libraries and 天津图书馆园区馆 might refer to one such branch

Comment: 园区 is a common word in Chinese, e.g.: 天津双港科技产业园区 is an industrial park, 上海张江高科技园区 is a high tech park, etc. So, **园区**馆 here is a branch in some nearby **park**. This is a Chinese style name for a branch of a museum, library, store, restaurant, etc. Generally, we speak "某某**分馆**" or "某某**分店**" (the branch in some place), but sometimes the word "分" (branch) is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is confusing. If you search it you'll find the (complete) name should be [天津图书馆海河教育园区图书馆](http://hhjyy.tjl.tj.cn/TJHHPortal/ArticleChannel.aspx?ChannelID=274).

`(天津)海河教育园区` (`Tianjin Haihe Education Park`) is used for specifying the location of the branch library here. Note that [园区](http://cidian.xpcha.com/23069nia41f.html) is usually used as a term, which means "集中发展某种事业的地区" (`key development area for some kind of enterprise`).

I guess that the name `天津图书馆海河教育园区图书馆` is just too long to write on the road sign so it's shorted.

At last to answer your question directly the sentence should be parsed as

- 天津 = Tianjin, the city you live in.
- 图书馆 = library
- (海河教育)园区 = (Haihe education) park
- 馆 = branch library

Comment: reason for shortening:cf.CCG Ch.25 Abbreviations and omissions. "A highly significant feature of C sentence and discourse structure is the avoidance of repetition wherever possible. sentences are abbreviated and words omitted where context and co-text make the meaning clear...."